# Displaying different types of stimuli within a trial - PsychoPy Coding

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, types, psychopy

I am facing an issue that I do not know how to solve. I created different trials with blocks of stimuli. Each block consists either of words being shown or audio files being played. To keep the attention of the subjects, I have to incorporate target items which are either an image or a word. So far I managed to replace a random stimulus of the blocks with the target, but I do not know how to display the target item. 
To explain the problem a little further:
I am creating random lists of stimuli and with the probability of 1/3 one stimulus of each list is replaced by a target item. This is no problem if the target item is the same type as the items in the list. However, when I am trying to display an image in a block with words or audios this does not work. Because the lists are run by a code that is specific to the type of the list items.

This is how I exchange on item of the stimulus list (in this case a list of words) with a random item from the target list (a list containing words and pathways to images):

```
    #randomly swapping an item of the list with a probability of 1/3 
    print(WordV_item) #debug check
    swap= random.choice(prob)
    print(swap) #debug check
    if swap == 1:
        a= list(range(1,len(WordV_item)))
        m= random.choice(a)
        WordV_item[m] = random.choice(Target)
    print(WordV_item) #debug check
```

Afterwards I am running each list with a specific code that either displays them as text on a screen or plays them as audio files. 
What I need is something to understand if there is a target item in the list that has to be displayed differently. 
I'm just not sure how to make this happen. I was thinking maybe I could build in an if condition that checks when the code is running if the list items are target items and runs them differently, but I am unsure how I could make this work.

Thank you very much in advance!
I could also upload my code but it's very lengthy, so I'd rather try to explain it a bit better if the issue is not clear.

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

This question is perhaps too wordy and imprecise to give a specific coding-based answer, but below is just a very general hint as to how to handle multiple stimulus types. I'm assuming that you have associated values for each trial that specify the type of stimulus and some value to be used for that stimulus (e.g. some text, an image filename, or a sound filename):

```
if trial_type == 'text':
    your_text_stimulus.text = trial_value # e.g. 'Hello!'
    your_text_stimulus.draw()
elif trial_type == 'picture':
    your_image_stimulus.image = trial_value # e.g. 'cat.jpg'
    your_image_stimulus.draw()
else: # assume it is audio
    your_sound_stimulus.sound = trial_value # e.g. 'dog.wav'
    your_sound_stimulus.play()
```

This might not fit your actual needs. If so, for more back-and-forth discussion, perhaps this venue isn't the ideal format and you should try the support forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org